# Liferay - obtain data directory

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

How can I obtain in Liferay portlet (JSP) the directory of the `data` folder (usually it's in the home directory of liferay)? I tried using the `DLFolderLocalServiceUtil`, but I've failed.

Thanks!

Comment: I fear that the next question is: How do I know which file to open from there - they're not named like the ones I uploaded... In case someone has this question (doesn't need to be you): You should access the document library through the DL* API. In fact, the document library doesn't need to be stored in that directory - or in the filesystem at all.

Answer (score 2):

The following property specifies where would the documents be stored:

```
dl.store.file.system.root.dir=${liferay.home}/data/document_library
```

So I think you can use:

```
String documentPath = PropsUtil.get("dl.store.file.system.root.dir")
```

to get the value of this property in your custom plugin.

**Caution** (inspiration from Olaf's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195099/liferay-obtain-data-directory#comment16343444_12195099) ) [image]
If you want to access the files/documents which you have uploaded from the `Documents & Media` portlets, better use the [DLApp*Services](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service) to get them. This will help your implementation be clean and will also help in a smooth upgrade as Liferay is free to change the way it stores the files for `Documents & Media` portlets. Thank's Olaf.

Comment: to be exact: The data folder is rather *defined* as ${liferay.home}/data - following that, it's used as the default home folder of the document library, but that is not mandatory. It's hard to answer the question without knowing the underlying problem - I fell into the same trap when I wrote that comment at the question